# Is there a way to merge two branches without losing files and changes?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

is there a way to merge two branches without losing files and changes?

I have this situation:
**Branch A contains:**

- *file A* (different from file A from branch B)
- *file B* (different from file B from branch B)

**Branch B contains:**

- *file A*
- *file B*
- *file C*

Now I want to merge the branch A to branch B, the problem is that when I try to do that all changes from branch B are ignored, even the file C is deleted. How can I do that without losing changes from branch A and also from branch B? Because git didn't show me any conflicts between these files.

Comment: Hi, did you try to commit on each branch and push first, then merge both branches to master(or another common one)?

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental error here lies in thinking that `git merge` has *two* inputs—your branch and some other branch.  This is not the case: it has *three* inputs, none of which is a *branch*.  The three inputs are *commits*.

Let's draw some commits, and the branch names that remember the *last* commit that goes in each branch:

```
          o--o--A   <-- branch-A
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--B   <-- branch-B
```

If you run `git checkout branch-A`, what you get is *commit* `A`, because the name `branch-A` points to that particular commit.  The same holds for `git checkout branch-B`.  Comparing these two commits shows some difference(s) in some file(s).  That does matter, but *not all that much*.

From commit `A`, we can work backwards (as `git log` would) to an unnamed commit, then another unnamed commit, then commit `*`.  From `B`, we can do the same thing, and if we do we arrive also at commit `*`.  So commit `*`—the *merge base* of the proposed merge operation—is the *best common commit*, the best commit that's on *both* branches.

The way merge works is to run *two* `git diff`s:

- The first compares the snapshot in commit `*` to that in commit `A`, to see what someone changed on that path.
- The second compares the snapshot in commit `*` to that in commit `B`, to see what someone changed on that path.

Then Git *combines* these two sets of changes.  The resulting combined changes, if they have no conflicts, get applied to the snapshot *from commit `*`*.

Having combined the two sets of changes and applied them correctly—or as correctly as Git can determine—Git goes on to make a new commit, mostly in the usual way.  The new commit causes whichever branch you have *checked out* (one of the two branch-A or branch-B names) to get updated to point to the new commit.  The new commit has *two* parents, which are commits `A` and `B`.  So the end result is:

```
          o--o--A
         /       \
...--o--*         M   <-- branch-<whichever> (HEAD)
         \       /
          o--o--B
```

with whichever branch name *didn't* move, still pointing to either `A` or `B`.

The *snapshot* in new merge commit `M` is that from `*`, plus *both sets of changes*.  If `A` didn't change something from `*`, but `B` did change something from `*`, you get `B`'s changes.  If `A` did change something and `B` didn't, you get `A`'s changes.  If both changed the *same* lines of the *same* file, *then* you get a merge conflict—and you have to finish the merge job and make `M` yourself.

(If file `C` is in one of `A` and `B`, but not in the other, file `C` must either have been created-since-`*` or removed-since-`*`.  Merge combines *create new file* with *nothing* by taking the new file.  It combines *remove old files* with *nothing* by removing the old file.  Given your text description, `C` must exit in `*`, giving you the *remove file* action.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the merge by checking out branch B and having no working changes, then run the following command `git merge A`.

The result will likely require a manual editing of the files to resolve conflicts before doing the final commit. The following output when initiating the merge would indicate need for a manual merge.

`CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in [file A]` or in file B. Or both.

Fix the conflicts manually, then do a `git add [file A]` to continue on with the merge. When all code conflicts are resolved and the code is compiling do a `git commit` to complete the merge commit into branch B.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I did that, and that's the problem because git didn't recognize those conflicts and it take the decision to remove the files that doesn't exists in branch A or keep the files from branch A.

Comment: I gave it a test on my local machine and it did not delete `file C`. And it created merge conflicts on files A & B, which I did intentionally by editing the same line in both branches.  Did your two branches come from the same root branch? I did a branch from `master`. Creating branch `A` first, then branch `B`. Then editing two files in branch `A` followed by editing the same two files in branch `B` as well as adding a third file. I then did a merge of branch `A` into branch `B`.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.